# Can I move my chometz after the bedikah?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, cleaning, bedikas-chametz

According to [this](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/docs/Pesach%20Checklist.pdf) document, one should sequester all chometz in one's home either in a cabinet or behind a mechitzah prior to performing the bedikah (the search for chometz).

However, does this have to be the same place where the chometz will stay for all of Pesach? Or can you perform the bedikah on the areas that are not sequestered, and then move the chometz to a different sequestered spot before Pesach?

(Assume that the chometz will end up in the place you indicated on the bill of sale for mechiras chometz.)

If this applies to you, CYLOR.